# How can I prevent Alpine from writing duplicate messages in my Default Fcc folder?

Tags: alpine-mail

I have configured my Default Fcc setting like this:

```
Default Fcc (File carbon copy) = {outlook.office365.com/ssl/user=user@domain.com/auth=xoauth2}Sent Items
```

When I send a message, a duplicate always gets created in Sent Items:

`15187 17:31      Lastname, Firstname                  (38K) Re: I sent a message`

`15188 17:31      Lastname, Firstname                  (11K) Re: I sent a message`

How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: I am not sure, but it is possible that Office365 puts the copy of a sent message into the Sent folder by itself, and another copy is put there by Alpine, hence duplicate copies. Try to turn Default Fcc off whatsoever and send a test message. If you get one copy in Sent, that's probably the case.

Comment: I think that did the trick! Do you want to write an answer here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably Office 365 puts one copy of a sent message into the Sent folder by itself, and Alpine puts another one, therefore the duplicates. Turn off "Default Fcc" in Alpine at all and you should have only one copy.